# How to bind Pox with my program

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, openflow, pox

I have a small python program which acts like a virtual switch. Now I want to integrate it so that it could be controlled by a openflow controller POX.

1. I am wondering how would I exchange msg between switch and POX? Do I create a socket and bind it to port 6633(default port POX runs on) and send all the further openflow packets using that socket? How could I "connect" to pox.
2. What packets I need to send to build and maintain the connection? I receive
   `INFO:openflow.of_01:[None 1] closed`
   `INFO:openflow.of_01:[None 2] closed`
   `...`
   every time I sent a openflow packet.
3. how to test my switch without configuring the controller? (lets say i have several switches connecting to one controller, and I wish that they could communicate with each other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless specified otherwise POX is running on the TCP port 6633 (once it is running, you can check with `netstat -tnlp | grep python` on linux). You need to open a socket from you virtual switch to that port:

   ```
   controllerIpAddr = "127.0.0.1"
   controllerPort = "6633"
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.connect((controllerIpAddr, controllerPort))
   ```

   Then you use that socket for your Openflow traffic
2. I don't really understand that question but if you're asking how to test your switch without configuring OpenFlow I recommend using learning switches: `./pox.py forwarding.l2_learning`.

Comment: For Q.2 I think you get what i was asking. So my switch need to :1. send initiate openflow packet 2. process the pkt from controller.(manage flowtable). and the learning switch will do the routing and reply the request from my switch without and configuration?  I will check the openflow protocol to determine the details of the packet i need to send from my switch then. Thank you.